# Why creating model in any other location than client, meteor runtime throws exception?

Tags: meteor

I am a meteor newbie. I am trying out by building a simple app and it does nothing but shows list of items. I first tried out with hard coded model values in my client javascript code and it worked just fine. I then created a folder called 'model' under root of the application and created the model there like the following

> Favorites = new Meteor.collection("favorites")

with this change, meteor throws exception pointing to this line of the file on load. If I move this code to client the code works ofcourse that is wrong. The full code is @ https://github.com/ksunair/13favs It is a very simple solution has few files and less than 20 or 30 lines altogether. My client code is,

> Template.favorites_main.helper({
>        favorites:Favorites
>   });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following in order to clear your app of errors:

1. `Favorites = new Meteor.Collection("favorites");` (Collection starts with a capital C)
2. I moved `model/mainmodel.js` to `lib/mainmodel.js` so `Favorites` would be available as soon as the template rendered. I always put my models under lib (or in a subdirectory) so they will be loaded first. This contradicts what I see in other places including [discover meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/), so I'm unclear what the best practice is. In any case, it fixed the problem.
3. `$ meteor add accounts-ui` was needed because you referenced `Accounts.ui.config`.
4. You need to actually do a `find` in your `favorites_main` template. So it should look something like:

```js
Template.favorites_main.helpers({
  favorites: Favorites.find();
});
```

Comment: (1) did not know it has to be capital. I think my other sample examples worked with small 'c', but I will confirm. (2) is great catch. I guess, Meteor team needs to clarify it in the document. I had (3) in place and (4) I did try with find as well. But over all (2) seems to be the fix for me. Great information.

Comment: You are correct, just putting the collection did not fix my problem, I had to change the 'c' to 'C' as you mentioned in your answer to make it work.